# A 3D curve that originates from a face of a polyhedron

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I need a hand to help me with a study i'm making.

I have to unite two 3D objects:

- a face of a polyhedron with the points taken from `PolyhedronData`
- a 3D curve

I know how to make the curve a Tridimensional object, but I cannot take a part of the Polyhedron and put it on the starting of the curve.

Can someone give me a hint on how to make it?

I'm using

```
PolyhedronData[""RhombicDodecahedron", "NetCoordinates"]
```

to get the points of the given polyhedron, and

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}, 
  PlotStyle -> Mesh, PlotRange -> All] /. 
  Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1, rest]
```

to generate my curve of reference.